# Typescript allowing excessive properties when merging 2 objects

Tags: typescript

Could somebody tell me why in the following scenario Typescript raises no errors when introducing an excessive property:

1. 2 interfaces are created, each containing a different set of properties. It needs to be noted, one interface contains all properties as required, the other one does not.
2. They are then merged into 1 interface of its own type
3. 2 objects are created each having a type of each of the created interfaces. Needs to be noted, one object
4. Now, should we at this point introduce another object with an excessive property (see "incorrectObject" in the code), Typescript will give an error
5. However, Typescript allows merging an object, with the one on the right containing unrelated properties. See the code below:

```
export interface InterfaceOne {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    mood: string;
}

export interface InterfaceTwo {
    status?: boolean;
    address?: string;
}

export interface CombinedInterface extends InterfaceOne, InterfaceTwo {}

const objectOne: InterfaceOne = {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
    mood: "happy"
}

const objectTwo: InterfaceTwo = {
    status: true,
    address: "Some Street 3"
}

const incorrectObject: InterfaceTwo = { //Will work fine and will provide an error
    unmatchedProperty: 1
}

//However...
const interloperObject = {
    IrrelevantProperty: 1
}
//Here will work just fine
const combinedObject: CombinedInterface= {...objectOne, ...objectTwo}; // Replacing variable "objectTwo" with "interloperObject" variable gives no error. Why?
```

Playable version: [tsplay](https://tsplay.dev/wE5Abw)

Can somebody tell me why is that and how to correct this please? Thank you!

Comment: because extends enables to add properties to object. if you dont want this just use `type Combined= Interface1 & Interface2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.